# How to remove this fitting from hard wired dishwasher

Tags: electrical, wiring, dishwasher

I'm wondering how to remove this connector from my dishwasher, or what it is called?

It seems like it was pushed through the opening, after which little wings depressed, preventing it from being yanked out. I haven't had success in pressing them back in, and am not sure that's the intended removal technique.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are spring tabs on the left side of the fitting, against the mounting plate. As you suspected, squeeze them. You'll probably need a pliers to get them tight enough to the fitting to fit back through.

Loosen the screw or press the tab to release it from the flex conduit.